# Why can't I see structure inserted record from files while opening it in editor?

Tags: c, structure, fwrite

I have a problem with structure handling in C files. Here I wrote this programme to save bank customer record into the file. It's working fine but when I'm trying to open the data file[.txt (or).dat].It's showing some binary digits. Below is my programme.

```
/* Reading bank details and saving it on a file and printing it on 
screen*/
#include <stdio.h>

//Declaring a structure
struct bank_details
 {
  char customer_name[20];
  char cif_no[10];
  int ac_no,pincode;
 };

main()
{
struct bank_details bank;
FILE *file;
file= fopen("bank_file.dat", "w");
printf("Enter A/no:\n");
scanf("%d",&bank.ac_no);
printf("Enter customer name:\n");
scanf("%s",bank.customer_name);
printf("Enter CIF no:\n");
scanf("%s",bank.cif_no);
printf("Enter your PINCODE:\n");
scanf("%d",&bank.pincode);

fwrite(&bank, sizeof(bank), 1, file);
if (file!=0)
{
    printf("Data successfully updated into file\n");
}

fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: main() is deprecated. Use int main(void)

Comment: `main()` alone is invalid C according to the standard since C99 was finalized.  Some compilers let it through without comment; others pass comments on it (issue warnings).  You should set your compiler to reject it.

Comment: Since you write binary data to disk for the two numbers, it is not surprising that you read binary data from disk when you view what you wrote.  You need to convert to strings before writing — probably using `fprintf()`.

Comment: @machine_1 That's not my exact question. Please read and answer bro. Try to solve my problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yah it's working with fprintf() function. Is there any possibility to solve this by using different file functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using `fwrite` which writes a binary stream of the data you give it. [See here.](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) You should use something like `fprintf` instead:

```
fprintf(file, "CustomerName: %s\nCIF Number: %s", bank.customer_name, bank.cif_no);
```

[man `fprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf)

Comment: @machine_1 I dont want to do the work for the OP. I am sure they can learn how to add one extra item. It should hopefully teach them about format specifiers as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate this? I'm trying to open .dat file from folder to check inserted data. After opening, it 's showing numbers like binary form but I'm storing the whole record combined with chars and integers but I'm unable to read it while opening the filer.

Comment: @AnudeepSyamPrasad Did you read the answer? You are writing binary data to a file. Why do you expect to read something other than binary data when you open that file?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Can't we do this without using fprintf() statement. I mean using fwrite() function.  Your answer solved my problem but I want to know with fwrite().

Comment: @Anudeep No you can't. fwrite() cannot format data.